# Getting animation information from PSD file?

Tags: java, c++, parsing, photoshop, psd

I have been looking through Adobe's File Format Specification for PSD (Photoshop files) and cannot figure out where the details of animation are stored. I am looking for things like looping setting (how many time the animation should loop), duration of each frame, the number of frames in the animation, and which layers are visible on each frame.

I have a basic parser that will read through the bytes in the PSD file and can extract some basic information from the file. For the purpose of the project I am working on, I would really like to extract the animation information.

If someone knows where this data is located in the psd file, it would be really great if you could give me some tips of how to get at it. --would save me a lot of time that would be spent reverse-engineering the file format!

I am using Java for this project, but could adapt it to Objective C, C++, or C# if that is going to make any difference (e.g. in case there is already an existing parser that gets this information from a psd).

Comment: Did you find where it is located? From what I'm looking, it must be located at the **Image Resource** block, maybe using the ID *0x6375* or *0x6D6C*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a PSD plugin for Paint.NET which is Open-Source. You might want to take a look at for starters:

http://frankblumenberg.de/doku/doku.php?id=paintnet:psdplugin#download

Comment: Okay I will take a look! I am working on a Mac, but if this solves my issue, then I will just switch to my PC.

Comment: Well, it looks like that won't help me out much, so I just might have to reverse engineer it. Thanks for trying to help me out though!